# .Net Core Automapper: Problems with Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I am getting an error using Automapper. When I call map I am getting an error. It is explained in the next classes:

I have this Dto:

```
public class CVDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<CVPersonaDto> CVPersona { get; set; }
}
```

and this entity;

```
public class CV
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<CVPersona> CVPersona { get; set; }
}
```

CVPersona Entity is:

```
public class CVPersona
{
    public int CVId { get; set; }
    public int PersonaId { get; set; }
    public CV CV { get; set; }
    public Persona Persona { get; set; }
}
```

CVPersona Dto is:

```
public class CVPersonaDto
{
    public int CVId { get; set; }
    public int PersonaId { get; set; }
    public CVDto CV { get; set; }
    public PersonaDto Persona { get; set; }
}
```

Persona entity is:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Persona Dto is:

```
public class PersonaDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Body data is:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "title": "string",
  "CVPersona": [
    {
      "CVId": 1,
      "PersonaId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In the post call I do:

public async Task Post([FromBody] CVDto cvDto)
{
...
var cv = mapper.Map(cvDto);
...
}

The post call recieve the object without problems:

[image]

I AM GETTING THIS ERROR:

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
CVDto -> CV
CVService.Dtos.CVDto -> CVService.Entidades.CV

Type Map configuration:
CVDto -> CV
CVService.Dtos.CVDto -> CVService.Entidades.CV

Destination Member:
CVPersona
```

If I change in the class CVDto in the next code:

```
public class CVDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<CVPersona> CVPersona { get; set; }
}
```

It works.

AutomapperProfile is:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles: Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<PersonaDto, Persona>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Persona, PersonaDto>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<CVDto, CV>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CV, CVDto>().ReverseMap();
    }

}
```

My idea is to use CVPersona as DTO inside CVDto. Why is crashing? How can I solve it without using entity CVPErsona inside CVDto?

Comment: Probably not your issue but, your CreateMaps are redundant. `CreateMap<PersonaDto, Persona>().ReverseMap();` will map both ways, so you don't need `CreateMap<Persona, PersonaDto>().ReverseMap();` - that's what reverse map is for.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to put:

```
CreateMap<CVPersonaDto, CVPersona>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<CVPersona, CVPersonaDto>().ReverseMap();
```

in the AutomapperProfile.... with this two lines worked

Comment: You dont have to use these 2 lines. ReverseMap maps the second type to the first. SO using one of the above line will work